# Textbox overflow in the question flagging animation

Tags: bug, flags, user-interface

If you click on the **flag** link at the bottom of a question and switch between the first and second radio buttons, the textbox flows out of the parent `<li>` element while it animates:

[image]

Adding `position: relative;` to `.action-list li` somewhat fixes it.

Comment: For me, the 2nd link is *it doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate* - so for anyone else wondering what this is, try switching between the 1st and *3rd* radio buttons. Very minor bug though...

Comment: @DannyBeckett: Sorry, the screenshot is from StackOverflow, not Meta.

Comment: Main and Meta both show like this for me: http://i.imgur.com/uT2snLD.png

Comment: @DannyBeckett: Huh, that's odd.